# Android Studio Beta Keeps Deleting My Classes?

Tags: android, ide, android-studio

i have an issue with Android Studio Beta 0.8.6

every time i compile my project it deletes all my classes leaving only - or regenerate - `R.java`

Did anyone have this issue before? i already removed the IDE and installed it

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the `generated` folder which only contains classes generated by the Android tools (in most apps case, only the `R.java`). Therefore there's nothing unexpected in what you've shown.

Your classes should be under a `src` folder at the same level as the `build` and `libs` folder we can see in your directory:

```
module_name
  build
  libs
  src
    main
      com.your.package.name
        YourClass.java
```